# jquery validate remote call

Tags: jquery, validation

Got a problem with my form validation and a remote call. I have removed everythng from the page except the form and javascript

http://www.getoutofdebtfree.org/1.html

The php script always returns true or false using json_encode. The problem i am getting is if you enter a username into the field and press the submit button once you get an error in firebug and the form doesnt post. The error is

e[h] is not a function

The funny thing is if you load the page click the submit the validater works and you can then enter username and hit submit and it works just fine. Also if you load the page then enter username and click outside the field then click submit it validates and works.

Any ideas? Really am lost on this one, any help would be great.

JW

Comment: change your jquery library file download a new file and use that.
I think there is problem in your jquery library.

Comment: hi, the jquery library im using is straight from google docs. Ive tried several different version and still no joy.

Comment: The problem is that you have an input named "submit" in your form. If you name an input "submit" then you can't submit your form with form.submit. Check out the following Stackoverflow Question/answer with a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553584/cannot-submit-form-with-submit/3553600#3553600

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your submit button id "submit" conflicts with the html "submit" form method name...

Answer (score 1):

Nobody else has said this in an answer, but The Dog has it right. Do not name form fields "submit".